# Header Image won't cover page width

Tags: html, css, image, cover

I am continuing to practice with HTML and CSS. I am trying to make an image go the width of the page, centered below the header. For some reason, it won't work when I try options on stretching it. My guess is that there is an option I have yet to come across to do so.

CSS

```
#header {

height: 80px;
background-color: gray;
margin-bottom: 60px;


}

.container {

}

.MainImage {

background-image:url(computers.jpg);
height: 400px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;

}

.MainImage img {

position: relative;
background-size: cover;

}
```

HTML

```
<body>

<div id = "header">
<div class = "nav">

    <!-- container-fluid gives full width container of whole viewport -->

    <div class = "container-fluid">


    <ul id = "nav" class= "text-left">
        <li><a href = "#"><strong>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Technologies</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Programs</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Blog</strong></a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id = "nav" class = "text-right">
        <li><a href = "#"><strong>Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Sign In</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Contact</strong></a></li>
    </ul>

    </div><!-- end container-fluid-->
</div><!--end nav-->
</div> <!-- end header --> 



<div id = "Main">


    <div class = "MainImage">


    </div>


</div><!--end Main-->



</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xehu1tg0/

UPDATE: my IE 10 image error

[image]

Comment: try using CSS to centre the image first `text-align: center;` then you can increase the width to 100%. I also see you're using it as a background image, try adding `background-size: cover;` to the CSS rule for the image

Comment: Use `background-size: 100% 100%` -----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xehu1tg0/3/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `background-size: 100% auto;` to your `.MainImage` class, like so:

```
.MainImage {
    background-image:url(http://www.onlineuniversities.com/wp-content/uploads/improving-tech-literacy.jpg);
    height: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The `height` and `width` properties only affect the container element, not the background image itself.

`100% auto` essentially means the image size should be 100% the width of its container, and the height should scale automatically with the width (where you see two values like this, the first almost always relates to the x axis, with the second relating to the y axis.)

I hope that makes sense?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/w1020vu1/

Comment: This worked too but once again my IE 10 doesn't accept it, only Google Chrome.

Comment: What do you see in IE 10? I don't know of any obvious reason why this shouldn't work in IE 10, as it supports the `background-size` property (http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size)

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the code using IE10? Does it show the `background-size` property in the developer tools?

Comment: i uploaded the IE view in my post.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean inspect the code in IE. I check it out in jsfiddle in IE but I was told by someone else in the past that jsfiddle automatically formats stuff like that for the browsers.

Comment: It works in IE 11 for me. So, I suppose it should be ok in IE 10 too.

Comment: Sorry about that, when I say inspect it I mean open up Internet Explorers developer tools and inspect the element using that, you can find out more about the IE developer tools here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Developer tools are pretty useful for quickly experimenting/troubleshooting, I'd recommend you read up more on them :) Firefox, Chrome and Safari also have developer tools (for that matter, I think almost all browsers do)

Comment: It might also be the case that your version of IE is bugged in some way, there are tools you can use for testing webpages in IE amongst other browsers, e.g. http://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: Ok I will make sure to test that when i get home. Will keep you posted

Comment: @SeanDunwoody I also tested developer tools and if i remove the "background-repeat" feature the image repeats and fills the width of the page? That seems weird

Comment: @SeanDunwoody I added in the <head>  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=80" /> 

I read about my compatibility for IE being wrong from other places so I used this and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

First off, since you're assigning the image via CSS's `background-image` property instead of an `img` element with a `src` property, your `.MainImage img` selector does nothing.

As far as the `.MainImage`, styles, the `height` and `width` properties only affect the container element, not the background image.  To set the background image size, use this style:

```
.MainImage {
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for explaining that. I realized that Google accepted this format but my IE 10 doesn't. Can you explain why? @im1dermike

Comment: @AlyssaCooke: It works fine for me in IE10.  Please recheck your code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers provided, I determined that compatibility for my IE might be an issue.

In the < head > I inputed the following code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=80" />
```